# Replace uppercase to lowercase except first letter of each word in specific line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I want to replace names that I received in uppercase letters only. The names are mixed with other information which should stay as it is. `AUTH:` at the beginning of the line identifies it as a line where the names ought to be replaced.

```
TITLE: Average title
AUTH: SUPERMAN
AFF: Something
AUTH: THE NEW ONE
AFF: Berlin
AUTH: MARS-MENSCH
AFF: Planet Mars
```

It should then be

```
TITLE: Average title
AUTH: Superman
AFF: Something
AUTH: The New One
AFF: Berlin
AUTH: Mars-Mensch
AFF: Planet Mars
```

My question is related to but different from the Unix question "[Lowercase all but the first (Uppercase) letter from UPPERCASE in cyrillic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96286/lowercase-all-but-the-first-uppercase-letter-from-uppercase-in-cyrillic)" because I use roman letters and fail to adopt the proposed solutions.

To get the respective line, I use `egrep -rl ^"AUTH:"` and then I follow with `| xargs sed -r -i '/(AUTH:)/ ??? /\1/g'` where I don't know what to replace `???` with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> sed '/^AUTH/{s/^AUTH: //;s/\b\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]*\)\b/\u\1\L\2/g;s/^/AUTH: /;}' file
TITLE: Average title
AUTH: Superman
AFF: Something
AUTH: The New One
AFF: Berlin
AUTH: Mars-Mensch
AFF: Planet Mars
```

Comment: Could you please add a little information whats going on there? E.g. I wonder what the two `[[:alpha:]]` do.

Comment: @MERose They separate the first letter of a word from the following ones.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e '/^AUTH:\([^[:alpha:]]*\)/!b' -e 'h;s//\1/;x;s///                                                                  
    s/\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]*[^[:alpha:]]*\)/\1/g;x;s//\
\2/g
    y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;G;:l
    s/\n\(.*\n\)\(.\)/\2\1/;tl
    s/\(.*\)\n/AUTH:\1/
'<<\IN
TITLE: Average title
AUTH: SUPERMAN
AFF: Something
AUTH: THE NEW ONE
AFF: Berlin
AUTH: MARS-MENSCH
AFF: Planet Mars
AUTH: CONTRARY tO pOPULAR bELIEF, Lorem Ipsu'M is not simply random text. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.                        
IN
```

Portably to translate characters with `sed` you need to use the `y///` translate command and to explicitly set out each character to be translated. This actually does come in handy - there's very little confusion and/or guessing in that way.

This script splits each *AUTH:* line into two bits - One gets the first alphabetic character in any series of one-or-more alphabetic characters replaced with a `\n`ewline. The other bit consists of nothing but those first alphabetics and is `h`eld while the line is translated. After translation `sed` `G`ets the held bit, and replaces each `\n`ewline character with the first character following the last `\n`ewline in a loop until none remain.

Here's a `l`ook at what the *Lorem Ipsum* line above looks like just before `sed` begins the replace loop:

```
 \nontrary \no \nopular \nelief, \norem \npsum \ns \not \nimply \nand\
om \next. \norem \npsum \nomes \nrom \nections 1.10.32 \nnd 1.10.33 \
\nf "\ne \ninibus \nonorum \nt \nalorum" (\nhe \nxtremes \nf \nood \n\
nd \nvil) \ny \nicero, \nritten \nn 45 \nc. \nhis \nook \ns \n \nreat\
ise \nn \nhe \nheory \nf \nthics, \nery \nopular \nuring \nhe \nenais\
sance.\nCtpbLIinsrtLIcfsaodFBeMTEoGaEbCwiBTbiatottoevpdtR$
```

The *AUTH:* bit is stripped when the line is confirmed - it is reinserted last - and so it is not there, but the space that follows it - and whatever other chars that may come between - is there. You can see that all of the words begin with `\n`ewlines - `sed` trades those in order for each char in the string following the last one. `sed` doesn't distinguish between upper and lower case when saving the first letter of each word - they are all put aside and replaced later.

#### OUTPUT:

```
TITLE: Average title
AUTH: Superman
AFF: Something
AUTH: The New One
AFF: Berlin
AUTH: Mars-Mensch
AFF: Planet Mars
AUTH: Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsu'M is not simply random text. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 Bc. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
```

Comment: The problems that all (possible) answers will have to deal with (an impossible quest IMO ) are mainly apostrophes/proper nouns. `DON'T KNOW WHAT'S UP` is replaced with `Don'T Know What'S Up` although it should be `Don't Know What's Up`. No big deal to fix, I know, you can lowercase any letter following an apostrophe but then `O'MALLEY` becomes `O'malley`. Another thing: `MCCABE & MRS. MILLER` should be replaced with `McCabe & ...` not `Mccabe & ...`, PAIGE VANZANT should be replaced with `Paige VanZant` etc. Depending on the input file, this type of substitution can turn into a real nightmare.

Comment: @don_crissti - Oh - that's strange. I just changed it around. I probably won't handle VanZant... but, Don'T shouldn't be a problem, I think. Well, the apostrophe thing works *now*. But... VanZant is right out.

Comment: Yes, I think it's better now. As I said, it's almost impossible to deal with names like D'Artagnan or MacBride.

Comment: @don_crissti - I probably could handle that stuff - but not without an explicit definition list. Not in a simple script, anyway. I'm halfway imagining something like the global [`s///`ubstitution I used here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167050/52934) like `sed ... "s/\($(printf "\(...%s...*\)*" "$@")\).*/\1/"` but I'd need at least two passes at input and a whitelist array. I really appreciate your comments on this stuff, by the way - always spot-on, too. Weird that other people think about it too, actually.

Comment: In fact, it's good when `'T` stays `'T` because, as I wrote, it's names that I am going to fix and most words should start with capital letters. Look for example `D'ARTAGNAN`, `D'HONDT` or `DELL'ALBA`.

Comment: @MERose - wait what? You want letters following `'` apostrophes not to be converted? That's simply done - but the whole `D'ARTAGNAN` thing is another story altogether... Ok, it won't convert the letters following a `'` now.

Comment: Why not? `d'Artagnan` is the correct version, so the letter following `'` (also those following a `-`) should be capitals. We don't care it the letter in front of that sign is upper- or lowercase.

Comment: @MERose - letters following a - are not converted - remember this only does upper to lower case conversions - it doesn't go the other way. So if a letter following an apostrophe is already uppercase it will remain that way - as is also true for dashes. Both of these are represented in the example output. Otherwise though - the lowercase `d` in `d'Artagnan` - it gets much more difficult very quickly. I *can* do it... but what of *O'Malley* for example? It's very arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in the above code. We need `D'Artagnan` and don't care if `d'Artagnan` is the only correct version. We just think that `D'Artagnan` is still better than `D'artagnan` or `D'ARTAGNAN`.

Comment: @MERose - well, that's good. maybe you can find a use for it...

Comment: @MERose - either way, you will never get it right via a script like this (unless you manually fix the wrong stuff afterwards). You'd need a `dict` to handle all particular cases. And even then... Here's another one: `KING RICHARD III` - it's really ugly when converted to `King Richard Iii`.

Comment: True. But fortunately, we don't have a `King Richard Iii` in our dataset. However, I really appreciate the work of you all!

Answer (score 1):

With recent versions of GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^AUTH:/!b;s/([^\w:])(\w+)/\1\L\u\2/g'
```

With older versions:

```
sed -r '/^AUTH:/!b;s/([^[:alnum:]:])([[:alnum:]]+)/\1\L\u\2/g'
```

Comment: This works well for the names, but replaces `AUTH:` with `AUth:`.

Comment: @MERose, you may have an old version of GNU `sed` that doesn't recognise `\w`. Try by replacing it with `[:alnum:]`.